# How to fix com error -2147221005 "Invalid class string" when trying to filter outlook mails on a subject using win32com.client?

Tags: python, outlook, attachment, win32com

I was trying to download attachments from outlook which satisfy a particular subject but I got an exception that have no idea how to correct my code from. Below is my code:

```
import win32com.client
import os
get_path = os.getcwd()
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
message2 = messages.GetLast()
subject = message2.Subject
body = message2.body
sender = message2.Sender
attachments = message2.Attachments
for m in messages:
    if m.Subject == "Test Mail":
        for x in message2.Attachments:
            x.SaveASFile(os.path.join(get_path,x.FileName))
            print "successfully downloaded attachments"
```

And here is the problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LENOVO USER/PycharmProjects/FlaskProject/EmailFilter/TestFile.py", line 4, in <module>
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

Answer (score 2):

As the traceback shows, the error is at the line where you define `outlook`. Actually, there is no cap S in `GetNamespace` so replace this line by:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

but other errors occur, at the line where `body` is defined, a cap is mandatory for the attribute, such as `body = message2.Body`, and another cap issue in `x.SaveASFile`, it should be `x.SaveAsFile`

Finally, I'm not sure that your code will do what you describe as you try to download the attachments of `message2`, being your last message, while you iterate through `messages`, I don't see the point then.

Let me know if you need more help or if I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: I did the changes but still the pywin error persists,

Comment: what i want is this : I want to download all attachments that are of the same subject say "Test Mail" and are within a time interval of current day till 3 days past

Comment: my mistake, I read too fast your traceback and as I got the error I corrected, I assumed it was this one for you, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124915/win32com-client-dispatchoutlook-application-error-pywintypes-com-error-21) it might be because outlook is not installed on your computer, or that `Dispatch` can't create an instance of Outlook.

Comment: so what should  i do now

Comment: i have outlook installed on my system and also i have some emails that have "Test Mail" as subject and have multiple csv files as attachments and i am trying to download these attachments

Comment: for what you want to do it should not be difficult once the error on `Dispatch` is fixed. I'm not an expert so I try to find a solution with you. Which version of office do you have? If it's office14, `outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application.14")`  could work, so try with the number version of your office

Comment: my outlook version is 10

Comment: what happens if you try `outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application.10")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168655/discussion-between-ben-t-and-carl).